# Program that converts American distance measurements and metric system in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm just starting to learn Java and want to create a program that converts American distance measurements (inches, feet, miles) to metric measurements (mm, cm, m, km) using switch statements. However, my program sometimes fails to distinguish the difference between inches, feet, and miles. Can someone show me the logic error in my program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class P3_24
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      final double MILLIMETER_PER_INCH = 25.4;
      final double CENTIMETER_PER_INCH = 2.54;
      final double METER_PER_INCH = 0.0254;
      final double KILOMETER_PER_INCH = 2.54E-5;

      final double MILLIMETER_PER_FEET = 304.8;
      final double CENTIMETER_PER_FEET = 30.48;
      final double METER_PER_FEET = 0.3048;
      final double KILOMETER_PER_FEET = 0.0003048;

      final double MILLIMETER_PER_MILE = 1609344;
      final double CENTIMETER_PER_MILE = 160934.4;
      final double METER_PER_MILE = 1609.344;
      final double KILOMETER_PER_MILE = 1.609344;

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Convert from: (in, ft, mi)");
      String convertFrom = s.next().toLowerCase();
      System.out.println("Convert to: (mm, cm, m, km)");
      String convertTo = s.next().toLowerCase();

      System.out.println("Value?");
      double value = s.nextDouble();

      s.close();

      switch (convertFrom)
      {
         case ("in"):
         {
            switch (convertTo)
            {
               case ("mm"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to mm is: " + (value * MILLIMETER_PER_INCH));
                  break;
               }
               case ("cm"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to cm is: " + (value * CENTIMETER_PER_INCH));
                  break;
               }
               case ("m"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to m is: " + (value * METER_PER_INCH));
                  break;
               }
               case ("km"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to km is: " + (value * KILOMETER_PER_INCH));
                  break;
               }
               default:
               {
                  System.out.println("output units not recognized, must be mm, cm, m, km");
                  break;
               }
            }
         } 
         case ("ft"):
         {
            switch (convertTo)
            {
               case ("mm"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "ft to mm is: " + (value * MILLIMETER_PER_FEET));
                  break;
               }
               case ("cm"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "ft to cm is: " + (value * CENTIMETER_PER_FEET));
                  break;
               }
               case ("m"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "ft to m is: " + (value * METER_PER_FEET));
                  break;
               }
               case ("km"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "ft to km is: " + (value * KILOMETER_PER_FEET));
                  break;
               }
               default:
               {
                  System.out.println("output units not recognized, must be mm, cm, m, km");
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         case ("mi"):
         {
            switch (convertTo)
            {
               case ("mm"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "miles to mm is: " + (value * MILLIMETER_PER_MILE));
                  break;
               }
               case ("cm"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "miles to cm is: " + (value * CENTIMETER_PER_MILE));
                  break;
               }
               case ("m"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "miles to m is: " + (value * METER_PER_MILE));
                  break;
               }
               case ("km"):
               {
                  System.out.println("The value of " + value + "miles to km is: " + (value * KILOMETER_PER_MILE));
                  break;
               }
               default:
               {
                  System.out.println("output units not recognized, must be mm, cm, m, km");
                  break;
               }

            }
         }
         default:
         {
            System.out.println("input units not recognized, must be in, ft, mi");
            break;
         }

      }

   }
}
```

Again, sorry for such a noobish question.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to distinguish"?

Comment: You're missing `break` statements in your outer `switch` statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @rgettman Ahh thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rgettman commented, you're missing the break statements on your outer convertFrom cases.

```
        case ("in"):
        {
            switch (convertTo)
            {
                case ("mm"):
                {
                    System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to mm is: " + (value * MILLIMETER_PER_INCH));
                    break;
                }
                case ("cm"):
                {
                    System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to cm is: " + (value * CENTIMETER_PER_INCH));
                    break;
                }
                case ("m"):
                {
                    System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to m is: " + (value * METER_PER_INCH));
                    break;
                }
                case ("km"):
                {
                    System.out.println("The value of " + value + "inches to km is: " + (value * KILOMETER_PER_INCH));
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("output units not recognized, must be mm, cm, m, km");
                    break;
                }
            }
            break; // breaks the outer switch case "in"
        }
```

As shown on the commented line here as an example.  Without the breaks in there, it will just fall through to the next case i.e.:

```
    switch(0) {
        case (0):
            System.out.println("0 case");
        case (1):
            System.out.println("1 case");
        default:
            System.out.println("default case");
    }
```

will print out:

```
0 case
1 case
default case
```